# Telerik rad datepicker in decade mode

Tags: telerik

I am using the telerik raddatepicker as a Birthday picker. I need to upgrade this to support Decade mode. Is this possible with Telerik Datepicker?  User first selects the decade with Fastnavigation, then pick the month, then pick the date.

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpDateOfBirth" runat="server"
                            DateInput-DateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" 
                            DateInput-DisplayDateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
                            ShowPopupOnFocus="True" DatePopupButton-   ImageUrl="~/styles/images/calendar.png" Width="100"
                            FocusedDate="1/01/1970" Calendar-UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False"
                            Calendar-UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False" DatePopupButton-HoverImageUrl="~/styles/images/calendar.png"
                            Calendar-FocusedDate="1/01/1970 12:00:00 AM" Calendar-RangeMinDate="1/01/1900 12:00:00 AM"
                            Calendar-RangeSelectionStartDate="1/01/1900 12:00:00 AM" DateInput-MinDate="1/01/1900 12:00:00 AM"
                            MinDate="1/01/1900 12:00:00 AM" DateInput-ClientEvents-OnError="validateDateOnEror" Calendar-FastNavigationStep="12" Calendar-FirstDayOfWeek="Default">                                                                
                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only drills up to a year selector.  It's not built for supporting decades, but clicking on the header allows for it to easily select a month/year combination.

The AJAX control toolkit [calendar extender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Calendar/Calendar.aspx) does something similarly, but you have to drill up.  The header requires being clicked on though, which allows the calendar to drill up to a decade view (decade displaying in the header).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tried Ajax date picker, it full fills the decade requirement, but I can't use that since it does not support a client side event on error. I need to invoke some validations based on errors in the date control.